# Need to install MySQL Client libaries but RPM not installing them

Tags: linux, perl, mysql

I'm trying install the MySQL Client libraries for the Perl Mod of the same name but when I run

```
sudo rpm --install -v --allfiles MySQL-client-5.5.16-1.linux2.6.i386.rpm
```

and querying the rpm database shows the package installed, but the lib files aren't there.

```
 rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
 MySQL-client-5.5.16-1.linux2.6
 ll /usr/lib/mysql
 total 4.0K
 4.0K drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Oct 11 09:49 plugin/
```

I'm not finding the files in /usr/lib

```
ls -ld /usr/lib/*mysql*
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Oct 11 09:49 /usr/lib/mysql
perlstation:~\ ->
```

Here's the results of rpm -qil MySQL-client

```
    rpm -qil MySQL-client
Name        : MySQL-client                 Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 5.5.16                            Vendor: Oracle and/or its affiliates
Release     : 1.linux2.6                    Build Date: Fri 09 Sep 2011 11:27:55 AM CDT
Install Date: Tue 11 Oct 2011 02:38:14 PM CDT      Build Host: loki32
Group       : Applications/Databases        Source RPM: MySQL-5.5.16-1.linux2.6.src.rpm
Size        : 53026574                         License: Copyright (c) 2000, 2011,    Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. Under GPL license as shown in the Description field.
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Wed 14 Sep 2011 03:13:49 AM CDT, Key ID 8c718d3b5072e1f5
Packager    : MySQL Build Team <build@mysql.com>
URL         : http://www.mysql.com/
Summary     : MySQL - Client
Description :
This package contains the standard MySQL clients and administration tools.

For a description of MySQL see the base MySQL RPM or http://www.mysql.com/
/usr/bin/msql2mysql
/usr/bin/mysql
/usr/bin/mysql_find_rows
/usr/bin/mysql_waitpid
/usr/bin/mysqlaccess
/usr/bin/mysqlaccess.conf
/usr/bin/mysqladmin
/usr/bin/mysqlbinlog
/usr/bin/mysqlcheck
/usr/bin/mysqldump
/usr/bin/mysqlimport
/usr/bin/mysqlshow
/usr/bin/mysqlslap
/usr/share/man/man1/msql2mysql.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_find_rows.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_waitpid.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlaccess.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqladmin.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlbinlog.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlcheck.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlimport.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlshow.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqlslap.1.gz
perlstation:~\ ->
```

I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Which Linux distribution (and wich major version) are you talking about?

Comment: Linux version 2.6.18-164.2.1.el5

Comment: What does `rpm -qil MySQL-client` show?

Comment: Shows files installed in /usr/bin and /usr/share but nowhere else

Comment: What about the `-i` part? Specifically, check what packages `MySQL-client` depends on. There's probably a package like `libmysqlclient14` that contains the library you want. And please post the output of `ls -ld /usr/lib/*mysql*` (this exact command, please, not another one that doesn't work).

Comment: Oh, and please say what **distribution** you are running. (At a guess, CentOS? What version?)

Comment: cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18-164.2.1.el5 (mockbuild@x86-006.build.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)) #1 SMP Mon Sep 21 04:37:42 EDT 2009

Answer (score 3):

What were you expecting to see in `/usr/lib/mysql`? That directory seems to contain only plug-ins. The MySQL client library is `/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.*`. It should be there; probably not from the `MySQL-client` package, but from a library package that `MySQL-client` depends on. More generally, all dynamic library file names begin with `lib` and end with `.so`.

Comment: There are no /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.* in /usr/lib  ls /usr/lib | grep /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.*
perlstation:~\ ->

Comment: @phileasfogg If you typed the same command as the one in your comment, it's not doing anything useful: if you do have these libraries, then `grep /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.*` expands to e.g. 'grep /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16  /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0', i.e. searching the string `/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16` in the file `/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0`. To see if the files exist, run `ls /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.*`.

Comment: Good point, but as my find search above shows the libraries don't seem to be anyway on the machine.

Comment: @phileasfogg No, your `find` command is looking for the exact name `libmysqlclient.so`, but you should be looking for `libmysqlclient.so.16` (or some other number). Not that the `find` is useful: if you have the library, it'll be in `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

Its always necessary check the package dependencies with `rpm`. Do you have the other packages downloaded in the same directory where the mysql-client package is being installed from. Since `rpm` does not have provide dependency resolution it self, its necessary that tools like yum have come into the picture to make it easy for rpms installation. Incase of this, I suggest to either resolve the package dependency self, or better have yum configured on the host and let yum take the burden of dependency resolution and have them installed through rpm.

In your above case, if you are really seeing that your files are not installed while the rpm claims the files to be present in the package which is installed. A simple method to re-verify it would be.

```
rpm -ql MySQL-client-5.5.16-1 | xargs ls -ld
```

If you are seeing all the files present, then rpm is right that you have all the files present from the client package. If not, then there is something wrong, it could be that the mysql-client package was actually installed but some rogue user?/process had deleted those files from their installation place?. It could be possible. For which, rpm does not guarantee since it all it checks and references from its `rpmdb`. I would suggest to `erase` the package and reinstall the MySQL client package. Perform all the necessary dependency resolutions as necessary.

Also, not this is related to RPM, but incase you are intending to use mysql from perl, you do not necessarily have to depend on DBI/DBD::MySQL perl packages instead you can use standalone Tsucchi's Net::MySQL perl package, which does not have a need to bind to mysql libraries nor depends on the installation of mysql in anycase. Just fork/clone this package from github and you are all set to use mysql from perl non-interactively, there is also a small script that works as mysql shell incase you are interested. forked repository is at https://github.com/mnikhil-git/p5-Net-MySQL